# Why JDI Test Framework use static methods for pages

Tags: jdiframework

According to documentation https://github.com/epam/JDI

> Note: all fields and methods on your Site page are STATIC

Why there is such requirement? And if the test cases will work in parallel?
For example, we know the fact that if webdriver is static - we have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a requirement. This is possibility. You can use not static.

We recommend static because this do your tests shorter (with static import)

Paralleling works well because of Driver factory manage different driver instances for different threads. And elements has only "driver name"